# CX_FREEZE ERROR No module named 'scipy.spatial.transform._rotation_groups'

Tags: python, cx-freeze

moduleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.spatial.transform._rotation_groups'

My code is running but when converting to exe file using cx_freeze no error is coming but while executing exe file the above mentioned error is coming

what can be done i have already reinstalled scipy and all

```py
#  Codes used in which error is coming

   
import cv2.
import string.
from datetime import datetime
from gtts import gTTS
from pygame import mixer
from multiprocessing import Pool
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist
import define_constants as const
import os
import time


def get_names(path):
    name = path.split(os.sep)[-1].split('.')[0]
    name = string.capwords(name.replace("_", " "))
    return name

def get_images(path):
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    return img

def get_EAR_ratio(eye_points):
    # euclidean distance between two vertical eye landmarks
    A = dist.euclidean(eye_points[1], eye_points[5])
    B = dist.euclidean(eye_points[2], eye_points[4])

    # euclidean distance between horizontal eye landmarks
    C = dist.euclidean(eye_points[0], eye_points[3])

    # Eye Aspect Ratio
    return (A + B) / (2.0 * C)
```

Comment: You should include a minimal reproducible example of your code.

Comment: Hii i am using the same for face recognition application in which i am calculating euclidean distance.The code where i am using same is as below                                                   '''''''def get_EAR_ratio(eye_points):
    # euclidean distance between two vertical eye landmarks
    A = dist.euclidean(eye_points[1], eye_points[5])
    B = dist.euclidean(eye_points[2], eye_points[4])

    # euclidean distance between horizontal eye landmarks
    C = dist.euclidean(eye_points[0], eye_points[3])

    # Eye Aspect Ratio
    return (A + B) / (2.0 * C)

Comment: Hello.  You should edit your post above to include the code and also please include a fuller example. What you have included does not attempt to import the missing module. It may be helpful to visit the help center to read the advice on how to ask a good question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: thanks for the advice i will surely check for same but right now my issue is with  executable file created via cx_freeze as my code is running fine using python idle.Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happens with cx_freeze. I had a similar problem in the past. Frst make sure pip is updated then update csfreeze and all needed librarys. After that it should work. If it doesn't you need to manually import the missing library to see if that works. After updating pip just use this command:

`pip install [package] --upgrade`

Comment: library is importing as i am only facing problem in executable file and all the modules are already updated